# How to set HTTP_REFERER in cucumber+capybara step definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

How can I set the HTTP_REFERER request header for a request made from a cucumber step definition using capybara?

Googling around, I tried the following, none of which work:

```
header 'Referer', 'http://example.com/'
ENV['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://example.com/'
get '/', {}, { 'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://example.com/' }
get '/', nil, { 'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://example.com/' }
request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://example.com/' # raises ArgumentError

visit '/'
```

I'm printing request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] in the controller, to prove that it's not coming through. If I test the controller with a web browser, the referer is printed correctly.

Note that the 3-parameter use of get above, actually *does* get the HTTP_REFERER into the request environment observed by the controller, but it seems to perturb the request in a way I can't figure out; all that gets rendered is a doctype element.

I'm using the default cucumber driver, Cucumber::RackTest::Driver, with cucumber-1.1.3, cucumber-rails-1.2.0 and capybara-1.1.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since I'm using Cucumber::RackTest::Driver, the solution for me at the time of writing is:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.header 'Referer', 'http://example.com'
```

This solution was inspired by the following unmerged pull request on capybara:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/198

Comment: If you were trying `current_session` instead of `Capybara.current_session` with `cucumber-rails` as I did, you'll not be accessing the same object and that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Cucumber that well, but this [i.e. calling post instead of visit 'some_path'] works for me in Rspec, so perhaps a similar solution might work for you (given that it's also an integration test):

```
it 'correctly updates the last_login_ip attribute' do
  post login_path, { :email => user.email, :password => user.password }, { 'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'some_address' }
  user.reload
  user.last_login_ip.should == 'some_address'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately, you're using Rack::Test::Session#get, which supports setting request environment variables.  So that should work in cucumber steps too, because ultimately, that's what Capybara::Racktest::Driver ends up delegating to. sadly, it doesn't work; I'll update my question to include how it fails.

Comment: I'd say it's `ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers#post` because it's a normal RSpec example ('rspec/rails' is required in the spec helper)

Comment: Then that explains why it works in rspec and not Cucumber. Thanks for the feedback.